# how to speed up sort in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I would like to speed up hive process,
but I do not know how to
do it.
The data is about 200GB and about 300000000 lines text data, 
and I split it into 50file in advance, then 1 file is about 4GB.
I would like to get 1 file as a result of the sort then I select the number of reducer is 1 and the number of mapper is 50.
Each line of the data consists of word and frepuency.
The same word should be grouped and frepuency of it should be sumed.
All of files are gzip files.
It takes a few day to complete the process,
and I would like to speed up
it to a few hours if I can.
Which parameter should I chgange to speed up the process?

Comment: Don't split the file! Just compress it in BZIP2 which is a splittable format and upload it to HDFS. I guess you have defined an external HIVE table pointing to the HDFS Location? You shoudl provide more details : what is the Hadoop env, how is the Hive table defined and what SQL do you execute?

Comment: is not clear on top of what colum you perform sort, you are talking about grouping so far. is sort required or order?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply,
Yes, I define external Hive table pointing to HDFS location.
I show my pseudo code,

create external table A count int, word string, 
row format delimited fields terminated by '\t',
location 'HDFS path';

select count, word from A group by word sort by count desc;